# Tensorflow object detection API, using polygon labeled dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, object-detection-api

I am a beginner in machine learning, I am trying to do my own object detection using my own dataset. However, it would be more practical if the object is labeled with polygon shaped bound. yet tensorflow object detection API can only accept bounding box.

So is it possible to modify the API such that, it can accept polygon labeled dataset??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to give directory of the training set. But bounding box is recommended because during inference time, you will get bounding box around the object detected. [You can see an example here in tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

For labeling you can use [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg), which is very simple and easy to use also will increase the detection accuracy.

Comment: yes, LabelImg is pretty easy to use, thank you for your kind recommendation.

Comment: Imran, What about rotated bounding boxes? Are they valid too? RectLabel can give you bounding boxes with angles which are pretty convenient in some cases. If yes, bounding boxes with zero rotation will need to include rotation info too? Can you reply my question or point me to the code where I can check that @ericsenoei

Comment: Yes , rotated bounding boxes are also valid. If you are aware of the Image augmentation , then you would have not ask this question. In image augmentation ,We rotate,flip our image to get large data set of some small number of image.

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali I do know image augmentation but I was asking especially about the rotation of the bounding box (no 0,90,180,270 degrees), not the whole image. For example, a pen rotated 45 degrees and draw a bounding box only enclosing the pen, not the background. Maybe in this case, you will think it will be no important the background but in a more special case like scratch detection, avoid background will be crucial.

Comment: was anybody able to train it successfully with polygon bounding boxes? as far as I know this isn't possible yet with the models

Comment: @PabloGonzalez: I am also looking to train a model with rotated bounding box (it's called oriented bounding box). Could you please share your views?